# Difference in viewing a webpage between Chrome and FireFox

Tags: html, css

Recently I have been noticing a huge difference in my website and how it is displayed on FireFox and Chrome. I can't seem to understand how this is happening. As you can see, here is the website in chrome
http://gyazo.com/8d57af4256eeebcb09971ffeee84b090
And here is the website in FireFox
http://gyazo.com/ee936e2f1cf4801f90171630ee14a558

And you can witness for yourself: 1v1LB.com

My problem is, the text next to the video thumbnail is fully readable on Chrome but the text extends too far on FireFox because it is too big. I don't understand why this is happening, but if I make the text smaller, it will be too small for chrome but perfect for FireFox. Can anyone help?

Comment: The whole layout is bigger in Firefox (1025px vs. 1098px). Are you sure you don't have Firefox zoomed?

Comment: Check the other answers first, but if there is a *genuine* difference between browsers there is a way to write css to target specific browsers but it requires a small js library to be added to the code.

Comment: I looked at the Web site in Firefox and Chrome, and the font sizes look *exactly* the same for me.

Have you tried it from someone else's computer? Does the same problem occur on other Web sites on your computer? What is your OS? What are your DPI settings?

Answer (score 0):

It can be silly but... Try to press CTRL + 0 on your keyboard while you're on your page in FireFox :)

Comment: I'm not an idiot. Both browsers are not zoomed in but at 100%

Comment: Chill out. Didn't say anything like that. People just do mistakes like that and they don't even think about a solution like that. The page looks fine in my Firefox, but looks just like on the screenshot when i zoom in a little bit.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude sorry lol. However, my main concern is, when you view it, does it not show all the text like in my original description? For example, here is it at 100% for me: http://i.gyazo.com/aa8fefe69a12f64abba509a0ed75ddf0.png http://gyazo.com/45fb718cd2cf722e1455df821a27c3a4 and there it is at 90. My problem is, is that I want majority of it to fit sort of like how it is on Chrome.

Comment: Oh, sorry then! I thought that you received this as a insult or something :) Here's how it looks in my Firefox: http://i.imgur.com/x0S51LV.png I think it's a problem with the YouTube embedded player - it's not anyway responsive here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have one of the pages zoomed, like others are saying, it's likely there's nothing you can do about this.  Browsers simply render html elements differently.

Only thing you can do is style things accordingly and always test on all browsers.